# How to get the changes in following scenario?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am trying to understand how **git** works. So I initialized an empty repo and added a file to it as following.

```
cd /home/adnan/workspace
mkdir git-test
cd git-test
git init
touch README
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now I cloned it this repo using the following sequence of commands

```
cd /home/adnan/Desktop
git clone /home/adnan/workspace/git-test
```

after that I made changes to README file, committed them and pushed them to the first repo using following commands

```
cd /home/adnan/Desktop/git-test
vi README
git commit -a -m "second commit"
git push
```

Now running **git log** in both repos shows same thing i.e

> commit
>   cdf192f7e26e734c7a56cc830ade2e2d13c6fb0d
>   Author: Adnan Waheed
>    Date:
>   Tue Mar 1 14:05:12 2011 +0500
>
> ```
> second commit
> ```
>
> commit
>   f8b75838e728e46cae949f66ff86d29c0864d976
>   Author: Adnan Waheed
>    Date:
>   Tue Mar 1 14:03:23 2011 +0500
>
> ```
> initial commit
> ```

but I cant figureout how to get the changes in the original repo i.e **/home/adnan/workspace/git-test**. If I try to do **git checkout**, I get this message:

```
M   README
```

How do I get the changes that I made in the cloned repo and pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see an error message when you did `git push`? Something like this (assuming git > `1.7.0`)?

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 246 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/pfarmer/git-test/git-test
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/pfarmer/git-test/git-test'
```

Basically by default you can't push to a non-bare repository. But what you can do is a `git pull`, so try:

```
cd /home/adnan/workspace/git-test
git pull /home/adnan/Desktop/git-test
```

and you should see something like:

```
$ git pull ../git-test2/
From ../git-test2
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 161aeea..c66b221
Fast-forward
 README |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Comment: no, I didnt see any error. Push was successful. I know this coz when I do 'git log' on the original repo, it shows the second commit. I just cant checkout the changes.

Comment: Ok, so you are using git < 1.7.0, what do see when you do a `git log` in `/home/adnan/workspace/git-test`

Comment: @binW: I suspect that a `git reset --hard` in the pushed-to repository would get you where you want to be, but it's a bad workflow - you should be pulling, as Peter suggests. Unless you really know what you're doing, you should only push to bare repositories.